# When and how to use StandardScaler with target data for pre-processing

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-scaling

I am trying to figure out when and how to use `scikit-learn`'s StandardScaler transformer, and how I can apply it to the target variable as well.

I've read [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re) and, while the accepted answer maintains that it is not necessary to standardize the target vector, other answers suggested that it might still be beneficial.

So let's assume that I want to go ahead and standardize the target vector.
According to the syntax, the `fit_transform` method of a `StandardScaler` instance can take both a feature matrix X, and a target vector y for supervised learning problems.

However, when I apply it, the method returns only a single array. If I try to unpack two values, like in the code below, I get a "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" error:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_scaled, y_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X,y) # X is some feature array, y is the target vector

# This code will produce an error message
```

This is consistent with the documentation, which states that the return value is a single output array `X_new`.

Then my question is: why is there an option to add `y` to the parameters of the method? Does it change the way in which X is standardized?

If not, should I use something like the code below?:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler_X = StandardScaler()
scaler_y = StandardScaler()

X_scaled = scaler_X.fit_transform(X)
y_scaler = scaler_y.fit_transform(y)
```

Comment: StandardScaler.fit(x, [y]...) y is optional and present for the algorithm who need it. Some algorithm have a .fit(X, y) so the StandardScaler method needs to be compatible, in case you use a pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way of scaling both the features and the target in Python with Scikit-Learn for a regression problem would be wit pipelines as follow:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


tt = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=LinearRegression(),
                                transformer = StandardScaler)

model = Pipeline([("scaler",StandardScaler()),("regressor",tt)])
```